# How to show skeleton while ng-lazyload-image is loading by checking if current dom has class?

Tags: angular

I'm using [ng-lazyload-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image) to lazy load images in my Angular project, i would be able to show a skeleton while the image is loading, i'm yet using [ngx-skeleton-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-skeleton-loader).

To show the skeleton i tought to check if the image has `ng-lazyloaded` class in it as it's the only way to know if the image is still loading or not.

My code looks like this:

```
  <img class="image-cover" [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image"/>
  <ngx-skeleton-loader #skeleton class="image-cover" [theme]="{ height: '100%', 'margin-bottom': '0' }"></ngx-skeleton-loader>
```

And i would do something like:

```
  <img #productImage class="image-cover" *ngIf="productImage.classList.contains('ng-lazyloaded'); else skeleton" [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image"/>
  <ngx-skeleton-loader #skeleton class="image-cover" [theme]="{ height: '100%', 'margin-bottom': '0' }"></ngx-skeleton-loader>
```

But how can i check if img has `ng-lazyloaded`? If i try to use `.classList` on `productImage`  i just get that it doesn't exists.

PS: the upper code is just like "pseudo-code", it's just an idea.

I've tried even this:

```
      <img #productImage *ngIf="hasLoaded(); else skeleton" class="image-cover"
        [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image" />
          <ng-template #skeleton>
        <ngx-skeleton-loader class="image-cover" [theme]="{ height: '100%', 'margin-bottom': '0' }">
        </ngx-skeleton-loader>
      </ng-template>

  @ViewChild('productImage') productImage: ElementRef;

  hasLoaded() {
    if (this.productImage?.nativeElement.classList.contains('ng-lazyloaded')) {
      return false;
    }else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

But all skeletons are set to invisible once the first image is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ViewChild` can take only one element at a time so you are getting the issue, instead check each element ref with the same code you wrote, then you can check for each one individually!

```
 <img #productImage *ngIf="!productImage?.classList.contains('ng-lazyloaded'); else skeleton" class="image-cover"
        [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image" />
          <ng-template #skeleton>
        <ngx-skeleton-loader class="image-cover" [theme]="{ height: '100%', 'margin-bottom': '0' }">
        </ngx-skeleton-loader>
      </ng-template>
```

or you could try to pass it as a function which returns true or false!

```
<img #productImage *ngIf="checkIfLazy(productImage); else skeleton" class="image-cover"
            [defaultImage]="defaultImage" [lazyLoad]="image" />
              <ng-template #skeleton>
            <ngx-skeleton-loader class="image-cover" [theme]="{ height: '100%', 'margin-bottom': '0' }">
            </ngx-skeleton-loader>
          </ng-template>
```

ts

```
checkIfLazy(productImage: any) {
    const productImageElement: any = productImage && productImage.nativeElement ? productImage.nativeElement : productImage;
    return !productImageElement?.classList.contains('ng-lazyloaded');
}
```

Comment: should i add `ViewChild` in my TS? 

Because if i do so i get ` Property 'productImage' does not exist on type 'ProductComponent'.`

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk That function is not needed, or the view child (no code in ts), you can do it completely in HTML, Best to create a separate component to handle image lazy load, so that the same html is not repeated everywhere!

Comment: check out the [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/f1e6c0ab4bb3da3fef8c7b378b098dd6.png) even with no code in TS i still get productImage does not exist..

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk strange I am not getting the issue in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfs5jq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,tsconfig.json) could you check my updated answer!

Comment: Something strange is happening, i'm getting no errors until i add my component in app.module, once added i get the same error:  `Property 'productImage' does not exist on type 'ProductComponent'.`

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk What about my alternate approach does it work?

Comment: same issue [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/aa6554ec5d72c8e8244c6dfdd69d2e80.png) but if i remove ProductImageComponent from app.modules.ts > declarations i don't get that error anymore, but obviously i can't anymore use the component..

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Comment: I was trying to create stackblitz and had no issues with template property, i think that probably my app.modules is broken or something like that..